# Map ip and port to domains

Tags: domain, domain-name

I started 3 different java applications in a single machine. Here follows the url my applications

```
http://ip1:8084/application1
http://ip1:8085/application2
http://ip1:80/application3
```

Here the applications are stated with different port. Also i purchased 3 domain names to map with the above started application. I want the mapping like follows

```
 www.a1.com ->  http://ip1:8084/application1
 www.a2.com ->  http://ip1:8085/application2
 www.a3.com ->  http://ip1:80/application3
```

How to add each domain with corresponding url. I installed the above application in a windows server with different tomcat instances

Answer (score 0):

A domain name does not point to any specific port. It points to an IP, not to an [ip:port] combination.

I am **guessing** that you want to access these three java based applications via a web-browser (else I do not understand why you used http in your examples. Domain are not inherently http related).

http://servername.domain1.tld/ could accept connections on the default http port (80), and then forward that to `http://ip1:8084/application1/`

Next you do the same with http://servername.domain2.tld/. 
Except that you forward `http://ip1:8085/application2/`

That way you do not have to specify any ports and you can just request what seems to be a normal webpage on a normal default server while still being redirected to your chosen application.